# How to use a property of an object in asp:SessionParameter

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource

I am trying to get an `asp:SessionParameter` of a `SelectParameters`, to use a property of an object in session
instead of having a string in the session like `Session["CustomerID"]`

Something like `Session["Customer"]` where the property is ((Customer) `Session["Customer"]).CustomerID)`

I don’t know the syntax to do that, if you can help, I’d really appreciate it

Thank you

My code:

```
<asp:sqldatasource id="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnectionString %>" xmlns:asp="#unknown"> SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM getStoreCustomers (@customerID,@week,@day)"
ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient">
<selectparameters>
<asp:sessionparameter name="customerID" sessionfield="Customer" /> ?????? (what is the syntax to pass the property here?)
<asp:controlparameter controlid="ddWeek" defaultvalue="-1" name="week" propertyname="SelectedValue" /> <asp:controlparameter controlid="ddDay" defaultvalue="-1" name="day" propertyname="SelectedValue" /> </selectparameters>
```

The class I use is like any other class (but serializable)

```
[Serializable]
public class Customer
{
public int CustomerID
{
get;
set;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found how to, from peter.

"Use a regular parameter instead, and set the value in the Selectingevent of the SqlDataSource

```
<asp:Parameter Name="customerID" Type="String" />
```

in the event handler:

```
    protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["Customer"] != null)
        {
           Customer c = (Customer)Session["Customer"];
           e.Command.Parameters[0].Value = c.CustomerID.ToString();           
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand what you are saying, but I don't think the parameter is intelligent enough to get a property of the object stored in session.  I think it has to be a primitive type, or else use an  and explicitly set the DefaultValue property via code:

```
ds.SelectParameters["ParamName"].DefaultValue = ((Customer)Session["Customer"]).CustomerID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to handle the OnSelecting event of your sqldatasource and add the parameter there.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote following class to get this working for me:

```
/// <summary>
/// Allows to access field-values of a object in Session.
/// </summary>
public class SessionObjectParameter : Parameter
{
    public string SessionField { get; set; }
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    protected override object Evaluate(HttpContext context, System.Web.UI.Control control)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SessionField))
            throw new Exception("SessionField must be definied");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PropertyName))
            throw new Exception("PropertyName must be definied");

        PropertyInfo pi = context.Session[SessionField].GetType().GetProperty(this.PropertyName);
        if (pi == null)
            throw new Exception(string.Format("PropertyName '{0}' is not definied in the object at Session['{1}'].", this.PropertyName, this.SessionField));

        return pi.GetValue(context.Session[SessionField]);
    }
}
```

With this I can use it as a simple Parameter on the SqlDataSource:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsTest" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:con %>' SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Test WHERE ([Field] = @ParValue)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <costum:SessionObjectParameter Name="ParValue" SessionField="MySessionObject" PropertyName="Value" />
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```